# splitting sentences using regex

Tags: c#, regex, split

i would like to split a text (using a regex) to a dot followed by a whitespace or a dot followed by new line (\n)

i'm working with c# .Net

Appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string[] parts = Regex.Split(mytext, "\.\n|\. "); 
# or "\.\s" if you're not picky about it matching tabs, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression

```
/\.\s/
```

Will match a literal `.` followed by whitespace.

Comment: There is no literal regular expressions (/.../) in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression for that. Just use the overload of `string.Split` that takes an array of strings:

```
string[] splitters = new string[] { ". ", ".\t", "." + Environment.NewLine };
string[] sentences = aText.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.None);
```